# How include properties file for internalisation?

Tags: node.js, internationalization, dust.js, properties-file

I am working on a node JS project with the Kraken framework. Then I use Dust templating and makara for the internationalization. But actually, I have one .properties file for each .dust file and i would like include a main.properties for each other properties for sharing same content across the pages.

I try this in a properties :

```
include = main.properties
```

But it doesn't works.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mechanism for include currently. This issue is the one to track on that matter: https://github.com/paypal/makara/issues/11